# How to queries all the assignments from the repository?

Tags: lucene, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

My environment:

> Alfresco Share v5.2.d (r134641-b15, Aikau 1.0.101.3, Spring Surf
>   5.2.d,  Spring WebScripts 6.13, Freemarker 2.3.20-alfresco-patched,  Rhino 1.7R4-alfresco-patched, Yui 2.9.0-alfresco-20141223)
>
> Alfresco Community v5.2.0 (r134428-b13) schema 10005

When I start the workflow, I can assign executors - the list of users who will participate in the business process. Somehow I need to get a list of all those users.

There is an [excellent guide](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/webscripts/tutorial/tutorial.html), which shows how to use [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org) to get a [list of whitepapers](https://github.com/jpotts/alfresco-developer-series/blob/master/webscripts/webscripts-tutorial-repo/src/main/amp/config/alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/com/someco/whitepapers/whitepapers.get.js).

To interact with repository through REST I'm also use the Web Script Framework MVC.

But how can I get the list of assignments?..

I'm interested in how to look like the query in this case:

```
...
var assignments = search.luceneSearch("what should be here?");
...
```

Comment: All the assignees of one specific workflow, or of all workflows?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off asking the `WorkflowService` for that, rather than search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know who is assigned to a specific running Workflow instance, then I don't think you can easily do that via the search service. Instead, you want to be using the [Alfresco WorkflowService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/workflow/WorkflowService.html) to get that.

Most likely you'll want to grab the [WorkflowInstance](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/workflow/WorkflowInstance.html) for the specific running workflow, grab the tasks, and check from the properties on that.

If you look at [WorkflowPermissionInterceptor](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/blob/master/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/workflow/WorkflowPermissionInterceptor.java) from the Alfresco source tree, you'll see pretty much the logic you want, covering both individual assignees and group assignments.